# Spring - Paths in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

I am defining a freemarker bean in my applicationContext.xml and this bean needs a path to my template-directory.
It used to be:

`src/main/webapp/template/`

But i now want to store my templates under:

`src/main/resources/template/`

It used to look like:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/template/email/"/>
</bean>
```

Can anyone please help me to correctly define the new path?

Comment: yes it certainly does! :) Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering as a proper answer, so you can close the question.

You should use "classpath:" prefix to reference resources located in the classpath.

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/template/email/"/>
</bean>
```